# MobileFirst 8 javascript adapters and messages

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

i have some questions about MobileFirst Adapters:

1. We are implementing javascript adapters on a MobileFirst 8 server. 
   Where is the best place to write javascript utils functions?
2. I also have some utils on java classes (called from javascript adapters) and i need to use the ConfigurationAPI class to get properties. The problem is that the configurationAPI variable (instantiated with the @Context annotation) is always null. Why? How can i get properties values from Java code?
3. I have a lot of properties (for example low-level backend endpoints) that should be shared between all the adapters. At the moment i used the `<property name="" displayName="" defaultValue="" />` syntax, should i copy and paste them in all adapters?! Or where should i put them?

Thank you

Comment: The `configurationAPI` context works in pure Java adapters, not in "java in javascript".

Answer (score 0):

> We are implementing javascript adapters on a MobileFirst 8 server.
>   Where is the best place to write javascript utils functions?

JavaScript adapters allow for a single .js file, so your best place for any adapters JavaScript code is the same .js file...

> I have a lot of properties (for example low-level backend endpoints)
>   that should be shared between all the adapters. At the moment i used
>   the `<property name="" displayName="" defaultValue="" />` syntax, should
>   i copy and paste them in all adapters?! Or where should i put them?

See my answer to the following question. Once you add custom properties you should be able to handle them in the same way I mention handling other values from the adapter.xml file: [Unable to build adapters using profiles and properties in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40946310/1530814)

> I also have some utils on java classes (called from javascript
>   adapters) and i need to use the ConfigurationAPI class to get
>   properties. The problem is that the configurationAPI variable
>   (instantiated with the @Context annotation) is always null. Why? How
>   can i get properties values from Java code?

I've sent a question internally and will let you know once I get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..

1. So should i copy and paste the utils in all adapters .js files?

2. I tried those MFP CLI commands, but it exports only the connectivity parameters. I need to know if i can share custom properties between adapters without copy and paste them in all adapter.xml files.

3. Ok thank you very much!

Comment: See Nathan's comment - condigurationApi is available in pure Java adapters and not in Java code called in JavaScript adapter. You may need to create copies...